# Аналог setTimeout, работающий под Android (в Chrome)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

Пишу веб-страницу управления машинкой с камерой на ESP32. Предполагается работа в том числе через нестабильное соединение типа дачного edge, в котором любой запрос может задержаться на несколько секунд или потеряться. Для сохранения контроля приходится отправлять запросы типа "езжай вперёд" с интервалом около 100 мс пока соответствующая кнопка нажата, чтобы пройденное расстояние примерно соответствовало длительности нажатия. Страница с этим кодом корректно работает в chrome под windows, но отправляет только первый запрос под андроидом:

```
//Drive
function sendToRobot(text){
  const query = `${baseHost}/drive?var=${text}`
  fetch(query)
    .then(response => {
    console.log(`request to ${query} finished, status: ${response.status}`)
  })
}

function stop(){
  sendToRobot("stop")
}

function driveLeft(){
  buttonPressed = setTimeout(driveLeft, 100)
  sendToRobot("left")
}
leftButton.addEventListener('mousedown', driveLeft);
leftButton.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {clearTimeout(buttonPressed);stop()})
```

А как сделать страницу совместимой с андроидом? Копал в сторону webWorker, но ему ведь требуется отдельный js файл, который во-первых придётся отдельно хардкодить в прошивке ESP32 на C++, что будет не очень читаемо для потенциальных желающих развить проект (сам наткнулся на пару малочитаемых участков в примере, на базе которого пишу, неприятно), а во-вторых, я не понял не будет ли клиент после каждого нажатия на кнопку заново загружать скрипт вот по тому соединению, что окажется под рукой. Пока хочется без этих воркеров обойтись. Вешать страницу пока нажата кнопка тоже нельзя, видео с камеры на неё же идёт.

Comment: Почему бы вам не использовать вместо таймаута интервал, который будет без рекурсий так же каждые 100мл спокойно отправлять робота налево до тех пор, пока не будет вызван `clearInterval(<some interval>)`. Должно быть `function driveLeft() {buttonPressed = setInterval(()=>{sendToRobot("left")}, 100)}`, ну и там `clearInterval`. js не зависит от оси, только от браузера - но, может быть, если сделать код рациональнее, то дело пойдет.

Comment: @artomich Действительно, оба варианта работают в мобильном хроме, если не использовать их с зажатой кнопкой. Когда я в прошлый раз пытался разобраться почему страница работает некорректно на телефоне, нашёл несколько упоминаний проблемы именно мобильного хрома: (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=567800). Подумал что дело в этом. Без кнопок раньше не тестировал. Утром подумаю как поправить вопрос. Есть ещё одно подозрение: длинное нажатие во встроенном эмуляторе мобильного браузера хрома внезапно вызывает контекстное меню. Возможно, дело не только в таймерах)

Comment: @artomich подключил мышь к телефону. Теперь оба варианта работают почти как надо, только запросы доходят до робота с интервалом в среднем 250-1000 мс, неравномерно. Пару раз пришли все с интервалом менее 150 мс (двигатель не остановился), но из нескольких десятков попыток. После отпускания кнопки идти не перестают, но количество примерно соответствует времени удержания. Как будто таймеры работают корректно, а запросы складываются в очередь и отправляются по загадочным событиям. Вот вроде элементарная задача, а только в обработке кнопок три уровня сюрпризов)

Comment: @artomich рядом с обработчиками mousedown и mouseup добавил обработчики touchstart и touchend, теперь удержание кнопки работает на телефоне без внешней мыши! А в эмуляторе десктопного хрома так и вызывается контекстное меню вместо этого. Ну и интервал на телефоне всё гуляет за пределами допустимого.

Comment: Что ж, да, понял суть проблемы - действительно, на мобилке использовать надо touchstart и touchend. Чтобы не вызывалось контекстное меню, используйте `event.preventDefault()` в обработчике события `contextmenu`. Что касается запросов, тут, конечно, могут быть задержки, причем самые разные. Может быть, вам немного изменить логику? Скажем, пусть интервал работает и отправляет запросы до тех пор, пока не будет получен ответ (запрос дошел, все в порядке) и, как следствие, устройство не начнет движение. Аналогично и с запросом `stop`

Comment: Спасибо, preventDefault работает! Логику менять пока не хочу, потому что за какую-нибудь секунду, на которую задержится стоп, робот успеет повернуться на заметный угол. Вот уменьшить интервал для кнопок вперёд/назад можно, и добавить панель настройки периода. Теперь основная проблема - mousedown и mouseup срабатывают сразу после touchend. Есть какое-нибудь стандартное решение? Которое бы ещё работало на андроиде с внешней мышью, мало ли что) Костыли можно придумать, но вдруг есть) И не подскажете что тут принято делать с такими вопросами не по теме? Пока не придумал заголовок для всех проблем)

Comment: Самый безопасный способ определить сегодня тип устройства, с которого заходит юзер, это через `window.innerWidth` и `screen.orientation.type`. Если первое значение меньше или равно 760, а второе - содержит подстроку `portrait`, то устройство мобильное, а в таком случае, необходимо подключать обработчики тач-событий. В противном случае - назначать обработчики событий мыши. Можно было бы использовать `userAgent`, но гугл, например, планирует в скором времени этот объект исключить. На всякий случай - https://qna.habr.com/q/277777

Comment: И нет, не получится отследить, подключена ли к смартфону мышь... разве что спрашивать специально :) В принципе, вообще не представляю, зачем юзеру подключать к смартфону мышь

Comment: И да, ничего страшного, имхо, нет в дополнительных уточняющих вопросах в комментариях

Comment: @artomich А до меня дошло) preventDefault после touchend отменяет клик. leftButton.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); clearInterval(buttonPressed);stop()})